# .NET Core MSTest project can't find VisualStudio type or namespace in Microsoft namespace

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, asp.net-core-2.0, mstest

`Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 
Version 16.0.0
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.0.0+28729.10`

I added a `.NET Core 2.2` `MSTest` project and it added dependencies :

- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk v16.0.1 ( I updated to v16.2.0 )
- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk v1.3.2 ( I updated to v1.4.0 )
- MSTest.TestFramework v1.3.2 ( I updated to v1.4.0 )

I compile and get this error :

```
CS0234  The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) ...\packages\microsoft.net.test.sdk\16.2.0\build\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk.Program.cs
```

Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk.Program.cs

```
// <auto-generated> This file has been auto generated. </auto-generated>
using System;
[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestSDKAutoGeneratedCode]
class AutoGeneratedProgram {static void Main(string[] args){}}
```

Couple of observations :

1. Project is `.NET Core 2.2` but it's using package from
   `netcoreapp1.0` folder
2. NuGet package manager successfully added package `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk v16.0.1` but on build it has an unresolved
   reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   ...\packages\microsoft.net.test.sdk\16.2.0\build\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk.Program.cs

If we consume the `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` package, when we compile and build our project, the `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk.Program.cs` will also be compiled by the `csc.exe` during the build.

So the error message indicates the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestSDKAutoGeneratedCode` attribute can't be recognized well because something is wrong with the reference to `Microsoft.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll`.

**Note:**

1.`Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestSDKAutoGeneratedCode` comes from assembly `Microsoft.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll`.

2.`Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` package depends on `Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHost` package, and `Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHost` package depends on `Microsoft.TestPlatform.ObjectModel` package.

If those packages are installed successfully, the compile and build should work. So actually I think something is wrong in your installed packages.

> Some simple suggestions you can try:

1.Go `Tools=>Nuget Package Manager=>Package Manager settings` to make sure two options of `Package Restore` are enabled. And then delete the bin, obj folders and run a rebuild.

2.If #1 not works, try [clean the nuget cache by UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) in VS IDE, and then again delete the bin, obj folders, then run a rebuild.

3.Please update your VS IDE to latest version, 16.0.0 is too old, and latest version has fixed some issues.

> Project is .NET Core 2.2 but it's using package from netcoreapp1.0
>   folder

If you open the package in path `...\packages\microsoft.net.test.sdk\16.2.0\build` you can find this package only have three version of assemblies, net40, netcoreapp1.0 and uap10.0. Since your project is .net core 2.2, it will reference the assembly in netcoreapp1.0 folder. It's **expected behavior**.